# javascript Error in REST WCF url from Jquery using jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, rest

I am getting javascript error when I try to execute REST WCF Service from jsonp.

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
```

Timestamp: Thu, 7 Mar 2013 09:00:24 UTC

```
Message: Expected ';'
Line: 1
Char: 22
Code: 0
URI: https://google.com/ISCSOrderList/OrderListService.svc/RestService/GetOrderList?request=B36733DC-6DB5-4FB6-9A63-B25CE858CA28;FR;2010-06-27;2010-10-05&callback=jsonp1362646767878&_=1362646774807
```

I am using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function GetRestData() {
         debugger;
            var Guid = $('#txtUserGuid').val();
            var CountryCode = $('#txtCountryCode').val();
            var FromDate = $('#txtFromDate').val();
            var ToDate = $('#txtToDate').val();
            //jQuery.support.cors = true;


            $.ajax({
                url: "https://google.com/ISCSOrderList/OrderListService.svc/RestService/GetOrderList?request=B36733DC-6DB5-4FB6-9A63-B25CE858CA28;FR;2010-06-27;2010-10-05",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "GET",                
                jsonpCallback: "MyCallback",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(JSON.stringfy(data));
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(JSON.stringfy(errorThrown));
                },
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert(JSON.stringfy(jqXHR));
                }
            });
        }
        function MyCallback(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringfy(data));
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: If I drop your code into a fiddle I get a rather different error. "503 Service Unavailable" - http://jsfiddle.net/HQaPS/

Comment: @Snixtor : You are right because i have shared you a dummy url , not the exact one.I cannot share the exact urls for security reasons.

Comment: ahm did you try put semicolon on the uri ? 

;2010-10-05 make it like this ;2010-10-05;

Answer (score 1):

OP,

The issue that you're having is likely related to an error in your *actual* URL/resource. Unless we can replicate the error, we can't help you solve it. Providing code with a request to a URL which 503's won't get us anywhere, and is confusing.

Can you clone a piece of your private resource and insert dummy data where the sensitive information is?

Alternatively, can you copy and paste what you find if you look at your resource on `Line: 1 Char: 22` ? Maybe a few lines before and after to be safe.

Comment: While I don't agree that this should have been posted as an answer (it's a comment), I agree with the sentiment. This question would get much more attention were the issue presented in a more easily replicable manner.

Comment: @Snixtor you commented in response to the `503` and OP didn't seem to understand. Rather than add to the comment thread I opted to post an answer with the hopes of updating/editing it once OP realized the information provided was insufficient.